Fast scrolling in Android Studio
In Visual Studio Code, if the Alt key is pressed while scrolling, the scrolling speed is increased. For me, it goes from 3 lines for each scroll to 10 lines.
I was wondering if is there any alias in Android Studio that could help me do the same? Or at least, some configuration that could be done to help me in that aspect?
Thank you in advance for your help.

maybe this plugin can help you? https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12388-fast-mouse-scrolling

It's not quite like that @cyberbrain , the plugin that you suggested, implements a similar fast scrolling like browsers do. Visual Studio Code implementation, it's way different in certain aspects.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7573-fast-scrolling -- this looks like a more appropriate one.

As suggested by LazyOne, plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7573-fast-scrolling works like a charm to me.
The suggestion made by cyberbrain,  plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12388-fast-mouse-scrolling , seems to work as well, just different from what I wanted.
